# Is there any way of integrating react native with mediapipe?

Tags: android, react-native, webrtc, android-camera, mediapipe

Is there any way of integrating with RNCamera or any camera library in react native or through webrtc. I want to integrate media pipe in react native.

Answer (score 0):

React native is a UI library, camera access and media manipulation are purely native thing with UI binding done here by RNCamera.

MediaPipe mostly work with android system.

You will need to do your own RNCamera package combined with mediapipe (or find a lib that do the job you need)

[android and mediapipe doc for android](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/getting_started/android_solutions.html)

Comment: I tried it I am don't have proper idea related to android there isn't an library that helps me with that in react native??